# How to restrict unwanted users to remotely access my system

Tags: windows, security, remote-access, remote-desktop

I have windows 7 installed in my system. I want to manage my system in such a way that only users of particular ip in the network can take my system remotely and others not. I don't have to use third party software.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit *users* who have access to Remote Desktop.

- Right-click "My Computer" and select "Properties."
- Click "Remote Settings" on the right pane
- In the "Remote" tab click the "Select Users..." button
- You can then use add AD or local machine users to the allow list

This doesnt limit by IP address, though.  However, this should be more than acceptable.

Any particular reason you want to limit by IP?  Or were you not aware you can limit by user?

If for some reason you *have* to limit by IP. You could use the Windows Firewall and set rules to block all incoming connections to port 3389 (RDP) except the IP you want.